# Facebook PHP SDK, opera loosing session

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have the following basic code which works fine on chrome and firefox, but when I run it on Opera, I can use the login link, but on returning, it seems to have lost the session and I get "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user"

You should be able to test at http://www.leagues-online.co.uk/test.php

```
<?
    $appid='XXX';
    $appsecret='XXX';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => $appid,
      'secret' => $appsecret,
    ));

    $fbid = $facebook->getUser();

    $params = array(
      scope => '',
      redirect_uri => 'http://www.leagues-online.co.uk/test.php'
    );  // scope: read_stream, friends_likes
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

    $params = array( 'next' => 'http://www.leagues-online.co.uk/test.php' );
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional. 

    if ($fbid) {
        try {   // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
            $fb_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

            echo "<a href='$logoutUrl'>Logout</a> | <p>fb user: $fb_profile[id]</p>";

            echo "<p>Logged in as $fb_profile[name]</p>";

        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            echo "<p>Error!<br />
                <a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a></p>

                <pre>".htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
        }
    }else{
        echo "No facebook user
        <a href='$loginUrl'>Login</a>";
    }
    ?>
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT

It seems that it works OK on Opera too when I request the 'email,offline_access' priv's. I didn't think that you needed these to simply allow them to login but maybe I am wrong? I don't really want to have to ask for these when all I want it to get their ID and public info to allow them to login to my site using facebook.

EDIT 2

I was missing the javascript section which it seems is necesary. I thought that I would be able to link to the login page and get redirected back without that, but it seems I was wrong!